# ServiceStack returns UnauthorizedAccessException after usage of Route Annotation

Tags: servicestack, openapi

After annotation a dto with

```
[Tag("DocumentationSignoffs")]
[Route("/json/reply/DocumentationSignoffs", "GET", Summary = "Get DocumentationSignoffs", Notes = "Get DocumentationSignoffs")]
```

the get request returns a 403 Forbidden with:

```
    "ResponseStatus": {
    "ErrorCode": "UnauthorizedAccessException",
    "Message": "Could not execute service 'GetDocumentationSignoffs', The following restrictions were not met: '\n -[LocalSubnet, External, Secure, HttpHead, HttpPost, HttpPut, HttpDelete, HttpPatch, HttpOptions, HttpOther, OneWay, Soap11, Soap12, MessageQueue, Tcp, Grpc, EndpointOther, InProcess]'\n Unauthorized call was made from: Localhost, InSecure, HttpGet, Reply, Json, Http",
    "StackTrace": "System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Could not execute service 'GetDocumentationSignoffs', The following restrictions were not met: '\n -[LocalSubnet, External, Secure, HttpHead, HttpPost, HttpPut, HttpDelete, HttpPatch, HttpOptions, HttpOther, OneWay, Soap11, Soap12, MessageQueue, Tcp, Grpc, EndpointOther, InProcess]'\n Unauthorized call was made from: Localhost, InSecure, HttpGet, Reply, Json, Http\r\n   bei ServiceStack.Host.ServiceController.AssertServiceRestrictions(Type requestType, RequestAttributes actualAttributes)\r\n   bei ServiceStack.Host.ServiceController.<ExecuteAsync>d__53.MoveNext()\r\n--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---\r\n   bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   bei ServiceStack.Host.RestHandler.<ProcessRequestAsync>d__14.MoveNext()\r\n",
    "Errors": []
}
```

I'am surprised. I thought I only make documentation annotations. Why is this thrown and how can I fix it? Google shows some messages where people write about Restrict Annotation. But this is not used here. I do not want that our intention for a better documentation with swagger leads to trouble/breaks the api.

C# DTO:

```
   [Tag("DocumentationSignoffs")]
[Route("/DocumentationSignoffs", "GET", Summary = "Get DocumentationSignoffs", Notes = "Get DocumentationSignoffs")]
[DataContract]
public class DocumentationSignoffs
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public int[] Ids { get; set; } //todo is this working? because id of signoffs should be guid

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public int[] CustomerIds { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public bool? OnlyChanged { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public DocumentationType Type { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public int[] SubTypeIds { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public int? Limit { get; set; }
}
```

method signature of the serviceimpl

```
        [Authenticate]
    public DocumentationSignoffsResponse Get(DocumentationSignoffs request)
```

The Service is a partial class:

```
public partial class DocumentationSignoffService : BaseService
```

as soon as there is another partial class WITH method x the exceptions is thrown. example:

```
    public partial class DocumentationSignoffService
{
    [Authenticate]
    public GetDocumentationSignoffsResponse Post(GetDocumentationSignoffs request)
    {
        return Get(request).ConvertTo<GetDocumentationSignoffsResponse>();
    }
}
```

When I remove the Authenticate and the method of the second partial class the error disappeared.

Comment: Which annotation is causing this error? i.e. which one can you remove to resolve the error?

Comment: When I remove the Route annotation it works.

Comment: Can you change the user-defined route to not try redefine the existing [pre-defined route](https://docs.servicestack.net/routing#pre-defined-routes), .e.g. `[Route("/DocumentationSignoffs")]` as this may be causing the conflict.

Comment: Done. Now a request fired with Postman works, but with Swagger not. Reason: the generated url ist wrong: /api/DocumentationSignoffs it should be /api/json/reply/DocumentationSignoffs. In the /metadata documentation it is wrong, too.

Comment: BTW: I already annotated many dto's and some spot checks showed no problems.

Comment: it’s using the specified user defined route in its published metadata as expected. Will need to look into other ways to add metadata docs to predefined routes.

Comment: So I can try repro the issue, can you update your question to include the C# DTO and the method signature of the Service implementation

Comment: i've updated my initial question

Comment: The service is a partial class. Does that help? public partial class DocumentationSignoffService : BaseService

Comment: a get request for a similar service works like ever: public class AnamnesisService : BaseService. It's get request method signature is in principle the same

Comment: updated the initial info again

Comment: You're using a partial + a base service class, are you overloading `[Authenticate]` anywhere? Instead of using multiple verbs to call the same service impl, why not just have a single `Any()` impl where the service can be called from ANY verb?

Comment: Click on Authenticate leads to class AuthenticateAttribute. How can a class be overloaded? Only know method overloading. What do you mean with verb, and what exactly would I have to change? I would like to avoid bigger changes. It's old big code used by several services, bad tested. In usage is serviestack 5.11. Is there another solution? Maybe an annotation without side effects?

Comment: As in do you have `[Authenticate]` added on any of the partial or Base Service classes? where it would attempt to re-authenticate multiple times on the same request.

Comment: [Authenticate] is not used in BaseService, and BaseService inherits from ServiceStack's Service. There are 5 partial classes (only in this case, over all there are more for other classes). All have only 1 method, all use [Authenticate]. All involved methods have different signature. 4 are POST,1 GET. If I remove  [Authenticate] in 4 cases, so that's only 1 over, the erros still appears.

Comment: I'm not able to repro the issue with what's provided, which doesn't return this error and works as expected. If you can provide a link to a small stand-alone repro on GitHub I'll be able to investigate further to identify & resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your offer.  Until now I couldn't repro it in a small stand-alone repo. Maybe I'll come back to this the next days.